# hasMany relationship Laravel 5.4 Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a relationship in my models with foreing keys, protected table.

This is my models:

Lot.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Lot extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'auct_lots_full';

    protected $primaryKey = 'lot_id';


    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'lot_id', 'lot_id');
    }

}
```

Than related model Comment.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;


class Comment extends Model
{

    public function lot()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Lot::class, 'lot_id', 'lot_id');
    }
}
```

In my view I try to do this:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)

   <dt>{{ $comment->lot }}</td>

@endforeach
```

It result this:

> {"lot_id":391959148,"date":"2017-05-21","company":"MITSUBISHI","model_year_en":2005"}

Than in view I need to get only **company** information and I do this:

```
 @foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <td> {{ $comment->lot->company }}</td>
@endforeach
```

this result Error:

> **Trying to get property of non-object**

I try to do this:

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <td>
        @foreach($comment->lot as $lot)
           {{ $lot->company }}
        @endforeach
    </td>
@endforeach
```

And it also gives error:

> **Trying to get property of non-object**

How can I get `$comment->lot->company` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, to Snapey from [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hasmany-relationship-larvel-54-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object/replies/344179)

when you do this

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <td> {{ $comment->lot->company }}</td>
@endforeach
```

you are relying on EVERY comment having a lot and every lot having a company

You can use this to protect against empty properties

```
@foreach ($comments as $comment)
    <td> {{ $comment->lot->company or '---'}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Then the loop will continue even if the lot does not have company